# Java - multithreading and synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, wait, notify

I have two very similar programs each trying to run two threads OddThread and EvenThread and trying to print the odd and even numbers in sequence . While the first one works , the second one hangs . Can anyone please pinpoint the bug in the second program ?

The first one which works :

```
public class ThreadTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Odd Even test");
    NumHolder objNumHolder = new NumHolder();
    Odd o1 = new Odd(objNumHolder, "Odd Number Thread");
    Even e1 = new Even(objNumHolder, "Even Number Thread");
    o1.start();
    e1.start();
}
}

class NumHolder {
private int intCurrNum;
private boolean isEven = false;

public synchronized void printOddNumber(String tname) {
    while (isEven == true){
        try {
            wait();
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
    isEven = true;
    System.out.println("Thread Name="+tname + "===Number="+intCurrNum);
    intCurrNum += 1;
    notifyAll();
}

public synchronized void printEvenNumber(String tname) {
    while (isEven == false) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
    isEven = false;
    System.out.println("Thread Name="+tname + "===Number="+intCurrNum);
    intCurrNum += 1;
    notifyAll();
}
}

class Even extends Thread {
private NumHolder objNumHolder;

public Even(NumHolder p_objNumHolder, String name) {
    super(name);
    objNumHolder=p_objNumHolder;
}

public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        objNumHolder.printEvenNumber(getName());
    }
}
}
class Odd extends Thread {
private NumHolder objNumHolder;

public Odd(NumHolder p_objNumHolder,String name) {
    super(name);
    objNumHolder = p_objNumHolder;
}

public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        objNumHolder.printOddNumber(getName());
    }
}
}
```

The second code which hangs :

```
class PrintClass {
int intCurrNum;
private boolean isEven = false;

synchronized void printOdd(){
    while(isEven){
        try{
            wait();
        }catch(InterruptedException ie){
            System.out.println("Interrupted exception in printOdd()");
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
        isEven = true;
        System.out.println("Thread Name="+Thread.currentThread().getName() + "===Number="+intCurrNum);
        intCurrNum += 1;
        notifyAll();
    }
}

synchronized void printEven(){
    while(!isEven){
        try{
            wait();
        }catch(InterruptedException ie){
            System.out.println("Interrupted exception in printEven()");
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
        isEven = false;
        System.out.println("Thread Name="+Thread.currentThread().getName() + "===Number="+intCurrNum);
        intCurrNum += 1;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
}
class ThreadOdd extends Thread {
PrintClass pc = null;

ThreadOdd(PrintClass pc , String name){
    super(name);
    this.pc = pc;
}

public void run(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pc.printOdd();
    }
}
}
class ThreadEven extends Thread {
PrintClass pc = null;

ThreadEven(PrintClass pc,String name){
    super(name);
    this.pc = pc;
}

public void run(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pc.printEven();
    }
}
}
public class EvenOddPrintClass {
public static void main(String[] args){
    PrintClass pc = new PrintClass();
    Thread to = new ThreadOdd(pc,"ThreadOdd");
    Thread te = new ThreadEven(pc,"ThreadEven");
    to.start();
    te.start();
}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is this homework related? If one thread is "hanging", it's probably because your first thread has locked a resource which the second thread is trying to acquire a lock on; alternately, it could be waiting for a signal, but thread one never gives the signal. We need to know what's inside the `wait` function, otherwise it's difficult to tell.

Comment: @Lirik: It's the wait-method from java.lang.Object. The other thread keeps on waiting for the other thread to wake it with the notifyAll -calls at the end of the printOdd/printEven -methods, but probably they'll get stuck at either the method synchronization or the other thread falls through from the while-loop and other is stuck wait():in for the notify.

Comment: @esaj... oh, got it. I forgot about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you run your code in the debugger and step through both threads. It's very educational. You will see exactly where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  So initially the `isEven = false`.  If the `printOdd()` is called first then the `while (isEven)` test is false so `printOdd()` will exit *immediately* without generating any output.  The `while` loops in your first program only encompass the `wait` test, not the entire method.

Then when `printEven()` is called by the other thread, it will call `wait()` and hang since there is no other thread to call `notifyAll()`.

You only should want the `while` loop around the `wait` since you are going to exit after you print out the even or odd number anyway, right?  So the logic in the first program is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In both versions, isEven starts out as false.

In the first version, printOddNumber will skip the whole `while` loop, print the odd number, set isEven to true and notify the `even` thread, which will print the even number and notify the `odd` thread again etc. in sequence.

In the second version, printOddNumber will skip the whole `while` loop, including printing the number and notifying the `even` thread. After 10 attempts it will exit without having printed anything, and leaving the `even` thread hanging without ever having notified it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CountDownApp
 {
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 Thread count1 = new CountDownEven();
 Thread count2 = new CountDownOdd();
 count1.start();
 count2.start();

 }
 }

 class CountDownEven extends Thread
 {
 public void run()
 {
 for(int i=10;i>0;i-=2)
 { 
 System.out.print(+i+"-");

 try {
    Thread.sleep(2);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
 }
 }

 }

 class CountDownOdd extends Thread 
 {
 public void run()
 {
 for(int i=9;i>0;i-=2)
 {
 System.out.print(+i+"-");

 try {
        Thread.sleep(2);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
 }

 }
```

Comment: Sorry I did not want to use the sleep() for this purpose .